# Access Denied using Impersonation with ASP.NET Directory Services

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, impersonation, directoryservices

I'm using Directory Services to change a user's Active Directory password as part of a set of administrative tools on an ASP.NET website.

I receive the error:

> Error: Unable to change password (do you have permission?).
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception
>   has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>   ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Invoke(String
>   methodName, Object[] args)
>   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SDSUtils.SetPassword(DirectoryEntry
>   de, String newPassword)
>   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.SetPassword(AuthenticablePrincipal
>   p, String newPassword)

`Web.config` reads:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

When in the Visual Studio debugging environment the Set Password routine completes successfully, but not when accessing from a different machine. I am attempting to use impersonation to allow this request - the site can correctly tell me my domain and username (using Context.User.Identity) and can query Active Directory for a list of all users in both environments.

My PrincipalContext is:

```
new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DOMAINNAME");
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Isn't `<identity impersonate="true" />` impersonating the [IIS Authenticated User](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
<authorisation>
    <deny user="?" />
</authorisation>
```

This denies access to the anonymous user forcing the user to authenticate, which with impersonation will then become the active user. without this you're still connecting as the IUser guest account.

You also need to enable Windows auth in IIS.

Comment: I already had an `<authorisation>` section (which I had not included in the original post) reading: `<authorisation><allow roles="Group Name" /><deny users="*" /></authorisation>`. I've added this line in anyway, but it has not affected it. Windows Auth is enabled.

Comment: deny users="*" will deny all users access, whereas you only want to deny the anonymous user. It might be the wrong type of impersonation. The principalContext you're using might require an interactive user rather than an impersonated one. You may need to modify your app so that the user enters their current password.

Comment: I do need to deny access to all users who aren't in the specified role. However, I shall try to implement interactive user authentication.

Comment: I've not been able to make this work, though I'm unsure if I was persuing it correctly (WindowsIdentity - I never got an Impersonation level, only an Identification one). It is worth saying that my code can connect to AD and retrieve a list of users and properties about them (whether run within VStudio or from another machine), but it cannot make changes (such as SetPassword) - so some form of authentication seems to be working, while other bits don't seem high enough.